# ListenerException : Mkdirs failed to create /tmp/temporary ( full permission given to the dir.)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, spark-structured-streaming

I'm learning about structured streaming when I write the streaming data that time show this error

```
    CountQuery: org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery = org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamingQueryWrapper@604770e3
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Query Count [id = 4ce8572a-24c9-4cde-97e4-051426cbb15e, runId = 59c60d53-73ee-43a4-8792-d5907a888de5] terminated with exception: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 183.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 183.0 (TID 5072, 172.31.21.3, executor 1): org.apache.spark.util.TaskCompletionListenerException: Mkdirs failed to create /tmp/temporary-cf1c3598-8273-4cec-a54a-d6eca9d7d08f/state/0/0 (exists=false, cwd=file:path/app-20170712063557-0003/1)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I give full permission to the dir.

Comment: How did you define the streaming query?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are hitting this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19909

When you don't specify a checkpoint location, Spark will create a temp directory. This directory will be on the default file system (in your case, it's probably HDFS).

So there are two options here:

1. Give full permission to the directory on the correct file system.
2. Always set `checkpointLocation`.